# How to use JBoss 7 jar libraries in my web application?

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm running JBoss 7.1.1 and I can see that one of the libraries I need to use is already included in JBoss (I see it in  /jboss-as-7.1.1/modules/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/main/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar). How can I access it from my web app if it's not in web-inf/lib? Do I need to declare it in one of the xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) you either need a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

or a header in your `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Dependencies: org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl
```